# Value domain error when calculating distance using specific longitude and latitude

Tags: python, pandas, function, math

So I used the distance function found on "https://gist.github.com/nickjevershed/6480846" as shown below

```
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):

        # Convert latitude and longitude to 
        # spherical coordinates in radians.
        degrees_to_radians = math.pi/180.0

        # phi = 90 - latitude
        phi1 = (90.0 - lat1)*degrees_to_radians
        phi2 = (90.0 - lat2)*degrees_to_radians

        # theta = longitude
        theta1 = long1*degrees_to_radians
        theta2 = long2*degrees_to_radians

        # Compute spherical distance from spherical coordinates.

        # For two locations in spherical coordinates 
        # (1, theta, phi) and (1, theta, phi)
        # cosine( arc length ) = 
        #    sin phi sin phi' cos(theta-theta') + cos phi cos phi'
        # distance = rho * arc length

        cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) + 
               math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
        arc = math.acos( cos )

        # Remember to multiply arc by the radius of the earth 
        # in your favorite set of units to get length.
        return arc * 3959
```

However, When I tried to use it to calculate the value below, it gives me an math domain error.

```
    dist(47.62, 122.35, 47.62, 122.35)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-164-c70b6ce05167> in <module>()
    ----> 1 dist(47.62, 122.35, 47.62, 122.35)

    <ipython-input-78-5d1b406c1007> in dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)
         24     cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) + 
         25            math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
    ---> 26     arc = math.acos( cos )
         27 
         28     # Remember to multiply arc by the radius of the earth

    ValueError: math domain
```

I've tried other values and all work fine. Is there some hidden logic I missed in the distance function or is there a requirement for the values to be calculated?

Comment: Can't reproduce - works fine for me (Python 3.7.2). Maybe try restarting your session (Kernel -> restart) in case you've overwritten a value

Comment: Restarting doesn't seem to work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Which Python version? Is your code exactly the same as you have here?

Comment: Python 3.6.4. Jupyter Notebook 5.4.0. Both Anaconda distribution. The code is exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is coming the fact you want to calculate a distance between same points so the result should be zero.

but with problem of rounding, you have a value cos > 1

so its the reason of error. I suggest you to add a test:

```
    # with your sample dist(47.62, 122.35, 47.62, 122.35)
    # cos = 1.0000000000000002, not good
    cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) + 
           math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
    cos = min(cos,1.0) #to securise the value
```

in this case you have the waited result: 0.0